# Nodejs body-parser returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm having a lot of difficulties doing something which on video tutorials, seems pretty simple. I've set up a node app using express with a dummy html (via ejs). I'm trying to capture the data a user would enter through an input field (like a search bar) and trying to verify that node is capturing that data.

I have an ejs file with this form.

```
<form action="/input" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" placeholder="Enter the id of the product you would like to buy">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" name="submit" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus mr-2"></i>Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

In my app.js file, in the following order, I:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// setting up views
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// middleware for bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// render page 
app.get('/input', function(req, res){
    res.render('input');
});

// get input from text input 
app.post('/input', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.id);
})
```

Running this returns "undefined". I've tried swapping req.body.id for req.body which returns an empty object {} in the console. Any help would be appreciated. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Your code expects json,  `bodyParser.json()`, but the form doesn't send JSON by default.

Answer (score 0):

Be proud of yourself for taking on the world of Node server instances! Mostly the issue youre running into is Express specific. The order you declare anything when configuring Express initially is very rigid. Try moving the views config below your middleware setup for body parser. Ive setup hundreds of Express apps and my general goto first configs are always:

```
        app.disable('x-powered-by')
        app.disable('etag')
        app.use(bodyParser.json())
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
        app.use(cookieParser())
        app.use(compress())
        app.use(methodOverride())
        app.use(helmet())
        app.use(cors())
```

Before I do any registration for template frameworks.

Comment: thank you, but now it's not console logging anything anymore.

Comment: Change your encoding type to render JSON when sending data you want to be readable by the client.

Comment: how do i do that?